# Outlook 365 Macro to Enable/Disable/Run All Rules

Tags: vba, outlook, office365

My macros stopped working when I moved from Outlook 2016 to 365.  I am looking for correction to my code, below, to assist me with fixing the macro to enable/disable and run all rules, separately.

```
Option Explicit

Sub ThePurge()
Dim st As Outlook.Store
Dim myRules As Outlook.Rules
Dim rl As Outlook.Rule
Dim runrule As String
Dim rulename As String
Dim rulelist As String
Dim oDeletedItems As Outlook.Folder
Dim oFolders As Outlook.Folders
Dim oItems As Outlook.Items
Dim i As Long

rulename = "ThePurge"

Set st = Application.Session.DefaultStore
Set myRules = st.GetRules

For Each rl In myRules
    If rl.RuleType = olRuleReceive Then
        If rl.Name = rulename Then
            rl.Execute ShowProgress:=True, IncludeSubfolders:=True
            runrule = rl.Name
        End If
    End If
Next

rulelist = "This rule was executed against the Inbox and Subfolders:" & 
vbCrLf & runrule
MsgBox rulelist, vbInformation, "Macro: The PURGE"

 'Obtain a reference to deleted items folder
Set oDeletedItems = 
Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderDeletedItems)
Set oItems = oDeletedItems.Items
 For i = oItems.count To 1 Step -1
oItems.Item(i).Delete
Next
 Set oFolders = oDeletedItems.Folders
 For i = oFolders.count To 1 Step -1
 oFolders.Item(i).Delete
Next

Set rl = Nothing
Set st = Nothing
Set myRules = Nothing
End Sub

Sub DisableAllRules()
Dim colRules As Outlook.Rules
Dim oRule As Outlook.Rule
Dim count As Integer
Dim rulelist As String
'On Error Resume Next

'Get Rules from Session.DefaultStore object
Set colRules = Application.Session.DefaultStore.GetRules

' iterate all the rules
For Each oRule In colRules
oRule.Enabled = False
count = count + 1
rulelist = rulelist & vbCrLf & count & ". " & oRule.Name
Next

colRules.Save

' tell the user what you did
rulelist = "These rules were disabled: " & vbCrLf & rulelist
MsgBox rulelist, vbInformation, "Macro: DisableAllRules"

Set colRules = Nothing
Set oRule = Nothing
End Sub

Sub EnableAllRules()
Dim colRules As Outlook.Rules
Dim oRules As Outlook.Rules
Dim oRule As Outlook.Rule
Dim olRules As Outlook.Rules
Dim olRule As Outlook.Rule
Dim count As Integer
Dim rulelist As String
Dim blnExecute As Boolean

'On Error Resume Next

'Get Rules from Session.DefaultStore object
Set colRules = Application.Session.DefaultStore.GetRules

' iterate all the rules
For Each oRule In colRules
oRule.Enabled = True
count = count + 1
rulelist = rulelist & vbCrLf & count & ". " & oRule.Name
Next

colRules.Save

' tell the user what you did
rulelist = "These rules were enabled: " & vbCrLf & rulelist
MsgBox rulelist, vbInformation, "Macro: EnableAllRules"

Set olRules = Application.Session.DefaultStore.GetRules
Set olRule = olRules.Item("ThePurge")
olRule.Enabled = False
If blnExecute Then olRule.Execute ShowProgress:=True
 olRules.Save
Set olRules = Nothing
Set olRule = Nothing

Set colRules = Nothing
Set oRule = Nothing
End Sub

Sub RunAllRules()
Dim colRules As Outlook.Rules
Dim oRule As Outlook.Rule
Dim olRule As Outlook.Rule
Dim olRules As Outlook.Rules
Dim count As Integer
Dim rulelist As String
Dim blnExecute As Boolean
'On Error Resume Next

'Get Rules from Session.DefaultStore object
Set colRules = Application.Session.DefaultStore.GetRules

' iterate all the rules
For Each oRule In colRules
oRule.Enabled = True
oRule.Execute ShowProgress:=True
count = count + 1
rulelist = rulelist & vbCrLf & count & ". " & oRule.Name
Next

colRules.Save

' tell the user what you did
rulelist = "These rules were Enforced: " & vbCrLf & rulelist
MsgBox rulelist, vbInformation, "Macro: Run ALL Rules"

Set olRules = Application.Session.DefaultStore.GetRules
Set olRule = olRules.Item("ThePurge")
olRule.Enabled = False
If blnExecute Then olRule.Execute ShowProgress:=True
olRules.Save

Set colRules = Nothing
Set oRule = Nothing
End Sub

Sub EmptyTrash()
Dim oDeletedItems As Outlook.Folder
Dim oFolders As Outlook.Folders
Dim oItems As Outlook.Items
Dim i As Long

'Obtain a reference to deleted items folder
 Set oDeletedItems =                     
Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderDeletedItems)
Set oItems = oDeletedItems.Items
For i = oItems.count To 1 Step -1
oItems.Item(i).Delete
Next
Set oFolders = oDeletedItems.Folders
For i = oFolders.count To 1 Step -1
oFolders.Item(i).Delete
Next
End Sub
```

When I try to run this rule, I get a debug error on this snippet of code (stating a run-time error.  One or more rules is in conflict):

```
Set colRules = Application.Session.DefaultStore.GetRules
```

Comment: Does GetRules return a collection or is it empty?

Comment: Getting the run-time error that "One or more rules is in conflict. You must resolve the conflict before the rules can be saved. and this snippet of code is highlighted: Set colRules = Application.Session.DefaultStore.GetRules

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have some rule conflicts. Do you get any errors when you try to edit existing rules in Outlook manually?

The [Some rules are disabled, and you receive an error message when you try to create or enable rules in Outlook](https://support.microsoft.com/nb-no/help/886616/some-rules-are-disabled-and-you-receive-an-error-message-when-you-try) article describes a similar issue.

You can try one of the methods described in the article:

***Method 1***

> Rename your rules to a shorter name. To rename a rule in Outlook, follow these steps.
>
> For Outlook 2010 and later versions:
>
> 1.On the File tab, click Info.
>
> 2.Then, click Manage Rules and Alerts.
>
> 3.On the E-mail Rules tab, click the rule that you want to rename.
>
> 4.Click Change Rules, and then click Rename Rule.
>
> 5.Type a new, shorter name for the rule, and then click OK.
>
> 6.Click OK to close the Rules and Alerts dialog box.

For Outlook 2007 and Outlook 2003:

> 1.On the Tools menu, click Rules and Alerts.
>
> 2.On the E-mail Rules tab, click the rule that you want to rename.
>
> 3.In the Change Rule list, click Rename Rule.
>
> 4.Type a new, shorter name for the rule, and then click OK.
>
> 5.Click OK to close the Rules and Alerts dialog box.

***Method 2***

> Delete any old rules. To delete a rule in Outlook, follow these steps:

For Outlook 2010 and later versions:

> 1.On the File tab, click Info.
>
> 2.Then, click Manage Rules and Alerts.
>
> 3.On the E-mail Rules tab, click the rule that you want to rename.
>
> 4.Click the Delete button, and then click Yes to confirm the deletion.
>
> 5.Click OK to close the Rules and Alerts dialog box.

For Outlook 2007 and Outlook 2003:

> 1.On the Tools menu, click Rules and Alerts.
>
> 2.On the E-mail Rules tab, click the rule that you want to delete.
>
> 3.Click Delete, and then click Yes to confirm the deletion.
>
> 4.Click OK to close the Rules and Alerts dialog box.

***Method 3***

> Combine similar rules to reduce the overall size of your rules. If it is possible, combine similar rules to reduce the overall size of your rules. After you have combined similar rules, delete the rules that you do not need any more. To edit an existing rule in Outlook, follow these steps.

For Outlook 2010 and later versions:

> 1.On the File tab, click Info.
>
> 2.Then, click Manage Rules and Alerts.
>
> 3.On the E-mail Rules tab, click the rule that you want to rename.
>
> 4.Click Change Rule, and then click Edit Rule Settings.
>
> 5.Modify the rule as appropriate.
>
> 6.Click OK to close the Rules and Alerts dialog box.

For Outlook 2007 and Outlook 2003:

> 1.On the Tools menu, click Rules and Alerts.
>
> 2.On the E-mail Rules tab, click the rule that you want to edit.
>
> 3.In the Change Rule list, click Edit Rule Settings.
>
> Modify the rule as appropriate.
>
> 4.When you are finished, click Finish, and then click OK to close the Rules and Alerts dialog box.
>
> > Note If the rule is a client-only rule, you must click OK two times to close the Rules and Alerts dialog box.

***Method 4***

> Move your personal folders (.pst) file to a location that has the shortest path name. If you have rules that move e-mail messages to a .pst file, move your .pst file to a location that has the shortest path name as possible. For example, move your .pst file to a location such as C:\file_name.pst. To move your .pst file in Outlook, follow these steps:
>
> 1.In the Navigation Pane, right-click Personal Folders or the folder name that appears for your .pst file, and then click Properties for folder_name.
>
> > Note This folder will always be a top-level folder in the Navigation Pane, in Mail.
>
> 2.On the General tab, click Advanced.
>
> 3.In the Filename text box, make a note of the complete path and file name of the .pst file.
>
> 4.Click OK two times to close the folder_name Properties dialog box.
>
> 5.Quit Outlook.
>
> 6.Use Microsoft Windows Explorer to move your .pst file to the new location.
>
> > Note By default, the location for a .pst file is the drive:\Documents and Settings\user_name\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\Outlook folder. The default location is a hidden folder. To use Windows Explorer to locate this folder, you must first turn on the display of hidden folders. To do this, follow these steps:
> >
> > > a.In Windows Explorer, click Folder Options on the Tools menu.
> > >
> > > b.Click the View tab.
> > >
> > > c.In the Advanced Settings section, click Show hidden files and folders under Hidden files and folders.
> > >
> > > d.If you want to see all file name extensions, click to clear the Hide extensions for known file types check box under Files and Folders.
> > >
> > > > Note that hidden folders appear dimmed to indicate they are not typical folders.
> > >
> > > e.Click OK.
>
> 7.Use one of the following methods to open the mail item in Control Panel:
>
> > To do this on a Windows XP-based computer or on a Windows Server 2003-based computer, click Start, click Control Panel, click User Accounts, and then click Mail.
> >
> > > Note If you are using the Classic view, click Start, click Control Panel, and then double-click Mail.
> >
> > To do this on a Microsoft Windows 2000-based computer, click Start, point to Settings, click Control Panel, and then double-click Mail.
>
> 8.Click Show Profiles, and then click the profile that contains your .pst file.
>
> 9.Click Properties, and then click Data Files.
>
> 10.Click the .pst data file that you moved, and then click Settings.
>
> 11.When you are prompted that the data file could not be found at the old location, click OK.
>
> 12.Locate and then click your .pst file in the new folder location, and then click Open.
>
> 13.Click OK, and then click Close two times.
>
> 14.Click OK.
>
> 15.Quit Control Panel.
>
> 16.Restart Outlook.

***Method 5***

> Clear the on this machine only check box. If you use a rule to move e-mail messages to a .pst file, click to clear the on this machine only check box unless you are accessing your Exchange Server e-mail from different client computers. To do this in Outlook, follow these steps:

For Outlook 2010 and later versions:

> 1.On the File tab, click Info.
>
> 2.Then, click Manage Rules and Alerts.
>
> 3.On the E-mail Rules tab, click the rule that you want to rename.
>
> 4.Click Change Rule, and then click Edit Rule Settings.
>
> 5.Click to clear the On this machine only check box if the check box is selected.
>
> 6.Complete the Rules Wizard. Click OK to close the Rules and Alerts dialog box.

For Outlook 2007 and Outlook 2003:

> 1.On the Tools menu, click Rules and Alerts.
>
> 2.On the E-mail Rules tab, click the rule that you want to edit.
>
> 3.In the Change Rule list, click Edit Rule Settings.
>
> 4.If selected, click to clear the on this machine only check box.
>
> 5.Complete the Rules Wizard.
>
> 6.Click OK to close the Rules and Alerts dialog box.
>
> > Note If you use client-only rules that point to local resource files, for example moving items to a folder in a .pst file, and you use multiple computers to access Microsoft Outlook, rule conflicts may occur. Therefore, some client-only rules may be disabled.

Comment: I've tried all those and still getting the run-time error that "One or more rules is in conflict.  You must resolve the conflict before the rules can be saved.

and this snippet of code is highlighted:
Set colRules = Application.Session.DefaultStore.GetRules